# Is there any way to work around dynamically adding elements in Ionic Framework(Version: 3.13.1) using Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I've created an Ionic Framework(**Version: 3.13.1**) Angular2 application. I need to create an element, like `<button ion-button color='dark'>Submit</button>` dynamically. I have tried the following in 'ngAfterViewInit' function,

(In template I've an element `<div id='buttonTemp'></div>`)

```
let buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
buttonElement.setAttribute('ion-button','');
buttonElement.setAttribute('color','dark');
buttonElement.setAttribute('text','Submit');
let buttonParent = document.getElementById('buttonTemp');
buttonParent.appendChild(buttonElement);
```

If I add `<button ion-button color='dark'>Submit</button>` this line of code in my template, while rendering Ionic Framework compiles it and adds class attribute to it. `button button-md button-default button-default-md button-md-dark` are the classes that get added. It is rendering the proper Ionic compatibility style.

I think while creating element through js Ionic Framework compiler is not compiling the code. Is there any way to work around this dynamically adding elements?

Comment: 1.- What you're trying to do is a serious Angular anti-pattern
2.- What are you trying to achieve btw?

Comment: I want to create dynamic template in Angular2 which should rendered by Ionic framework. Actually I have created dynamic component in Angular2, which works well with the normal html template but If I'm passing Ionic specific element, it is not working.

Comment: but did you use the `ComponenteFactoryResolver`?